# Add (rainbow) colors to Ruleplot[]

Tags: color, style, cellular-automata

I'm using [Ruleplot[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RulePlot.html) to plot the rules of my cellular automota. I'm using multiple 'colors' (= number of states $k$ ) and I want to color them a different color than the default grayscale. The documentation says to use [ColorRules](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorRules.html). In ColorRules I found that if no rules are found [ColorFunction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) is used as default. I want to use `ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"` but when I try it I get an error.

```
RulePlot[CellularAutomaton[{5^3, 5, {1, 1}}], ColorRules -> {}, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

I don't want to manually provide `ColorRules->{0 -> Red, 1 -> Orange, etc}` because when I change $k$ I don't want to change all the colors by hand.

Comment: does `RulePlot[CellularAutomaton[{5^3, 5, {1, 1}}]] /. {GrayLevel[g_], 
   r_Rectangle} :> {ColorData["Rainbow"][g], r}` give what you need?

Comment: Yes it does! It feels a bit like an ugly solution but it does the trick. I will keep this question open in case a more proper solution comes by but in the meantime this will keep me happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ColorData[name]` as the setting for `ColorFunction`:

```
RulePlot[CellularAutomaton[{5^3, 5, {1, 1}}], Appearance -> "Arrow", 
 ImageSize -> Large, ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"]]
```

[image]

Use `ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"]` to get

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I meant